# User session termination issue

Tags: xmpp, openfire, jsjac, jappix

I implement XEP-0199 ping request to the server. Every 30 seconds, it sends whitespace ping request to the server. The server will be properly responded to this request. But I got some session termination issues from Openfire server. When I check open fire logs, I got the message is like

> 2017.08.08 07:41:32 org.jivesoftware.openfire.http.HttpSessionManager - Closing idle session: 97xxxxx27@xxxx.xxxxx/Jappix (1502188314211).

Because of this issue message delivery is failed